# Is it possible to force Hibernate to embed an Entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

In my use-case, I would like to `@Embedded` a class `C` in an entity.

Another entity refers to `C` with `@OneToMany` association and therefore `C` is annotated with `@Entity`.

I am aware that this seems like bad design, yet I believe that it makes perfect sense in my case.

Is it possible to force Hibernate to embed an Entity? If I try it, Hibernate complains about a missing setter for the id property of C.

I think the problem comes from this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate doesn't allow you to treat an `Embeddable` as an `Entity` or to embed an `Entity`. According to [Hibernate types](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-hibernate-types/):

- an `Embeddable`, doesn't have an identifier, since it's state is part of an owning `Entity`.
- an `Entity` cannot be embedded, because each `Entity` has a distinct life-cycle.

Since another class already has a `@OneToMany` association to class `C`, it's obvious you cannot turn it into an `Embeddable`.

More, a [bidirectional `@OneToMany` association](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) will perform better than [an embeddable collection](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-unidirectional-collections-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

What you can do, is to use it as a `@OneToOne` association in the entity where you wanted to embed the `C` entity. You can make that target entity be the owning side of the association so that the `C` association is bound to the target entity life-cycle.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just create the entity that you want, and in that entity, embed C as well. That way you have C in both classes, one as embedded and another as embedded of the new entity.

```
@Embeddable
public class Contact {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    // getters and setters removed.
}
```

and here is your embedding class:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Embedded
    private Contact contact;    
}
```

and here is the new entity that embeds contact also

```
@Entity
public class FirmContact {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int contactId;

    @Embedded
    private Contact contact;
}
```

And finally the class that insists the contact must be an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Business {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private FirmContact contacts;
}
```

It'll just be a couple of extra steps in java to populate the object, but it should do the mapping you want. I hope this helps.