# Hibernate: Can an @Entity also be an @Embeddable?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, relational-database

I am extending an existing application and data model. There is an Address (A) class which is @Embeddable. This is part of a large (ugly) table (B) which I will eventually normalise but, for now, I just want to reuse this Address class and create an Address table for a relationship to another, entirely different, Entity (C) and Class.

So can I reuse this Address class (say for example adding @Entity to the existing @Embeddable annotation), such that in my new context it is a separate Entity (table), but in the existing ugly context, it remains an embeddable entity?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949853/hibernate-embedded-entity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate - embedded @Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949853/hibernate-embedded-entity)